# Error while launching Hive

Tags: configuration, hive

I installed `Hive 1.1.0` on my server, and I received the error message below:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/map red/JobConf
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.initialize(HiveConf.java:3694)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.(HiveConf.java:3652)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4jCommon(LogUtils.j
>   ava:82)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4j(LogUtils.java:66)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:657)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>   ... 11 more

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This error is maybe caused by bad configuration of yours class paths. Do you have checked paths HADOOP_HOME, JAVA_HOME, HIVE_HOME ?

Comment: I checked them, and everything looks fine. I added HIVE_HOME, HADOOP_HOME, and JAVA_HOME in bashrc file. AM I wrong?

Comment: No I think you're right. Please, include your config files bashrc, hadoop-env.sh and hive-env.sh. You can also check all steps of your installation with this link [hive installation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hive_installation.htm)

Comment: This is my bashrc so far:export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
#Set SPARK_HOME
export SPARK_HOME=/lib/spark/
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
# Set HIVE_HOME
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
#Set Hadoop_home
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin

Comment: I think the problem comes from JAVA_HOME. JAVA_HOME variable have to point to a jdk installation, not jre. Also, Check installation with `update-alternatives --config java` and `readlink -f $(which java)` (find location of your installation.